# How to run a project in the yarn workspace with a package script

Tags: node.js, yarn-workspaces

I have a few packages managed by the Yarn workspace and a cli package that helps build them.

Is there a way to run CLI projects in the same workspace from scripts in package.json of each app?

My folder structure looks like this:

```
.\
|   package.json
|   yarn.lock
|   
\---packages
    +---app
    |   |   package.json
    |   |   
    |   \---src
    |           index.js
    |           
    \---cli
        |   package.json
        |   
        \---src
                index.js
```

Root pakcage.json:

```
{
    "name": "yarn-ws-cli",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "private": true,
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/*"
    ]
}
```

Contents of /packages/app1/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cli":"1.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build" : "node cli" // I want to run "/packages/cli/src/index.js".
  }
}
```

I want to be able to run "/package/cli/src/index.js" when I run "yarn build" in the app1 directory.

However, if you run "yarn build" in this state, you will get an error message that the module cannot be found.

```
\yarn-ws-cli\packages\app>yarn build

yarn run v1.22.15
$ node cli
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '\yarn-ws-cli\packages\app\cli'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

Thank you.